# MVC5, IIS 7.5 Deployment in DoD environment - 404, strange Url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, razor

I have a MVC5 application I am attempting to deploy in a DoD (STIG'd) environment. The application starts and global.asax runs the DBInitializer, which creates and populates the tables. Before I get to the main page, I get 404 error. Any ideas ? The page URL comes to rest on this page....

```
https://server-name:8080/Fitness/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FFitness%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FFitness%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FFitness%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FFitness%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FFitness%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FFitness%25252525252FAccount%25252525252FLogin%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FFitness%2525252525252FAccount%2525252525252FLogin%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525253D%252525252525252FFitness%252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252FLogin%252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525253D%25252525252525252FFitness%25252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525253D%2525252525252525252FFitness%2525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252FFitness%252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252FFitness%25252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252FFitness%2525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252FFitness%252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252FFitness%25252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252FFitness%2525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252FFitness%252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2
```

Comment: If I had to guess, you are not allowing anonymous access to the login action, which is causing the site to continually redirect to the Login action.

Comment: how do you allow anonymous access to the login action ?

Answer (score 0):

Admin turned on Anonymous for the Web Application and it started working. Thanks Tommy.